# Start application proxy

Tags: service-application

Access Services Web Service Application Proxy and Excel Services Application Web Service Application Proxy are showing stopped. But their parent Services show "Started".

I tried Stop and restart those services. They stop and start fine but the proxy still in Stopped status. Any suggession?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Tristans blog post:

http://tristanwatkins.com/index.php/fixing-the-usage-and-health-data-collection-sa/

Find the ID of the service application proxy:

```
Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy
```

Copy the ID for the Service Application, then run the following two lines of PowerShell:

```
$UP = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where {$_.ID -eq "<PASTE COPIED ID HERE>"}
$UP.Provision()
```

Comment: Edited to add solution into post (in case the link dies).