# Sharepoint Store: Apps not enabled?

Tags: 2013

I am new to SP 2013; however, I have completed setup of a three-tier server farm (SP2013, Database and OWA Servers).  My problem now is specifically related to the SharePoint Store, as I receive the message:

**Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps.**

Here's what I have done so far:

***Apps Domain Setup*:**

1. **New forward lookup zone** = contosoapps.com
2. **Alias** = *
3. **FQDN** = contosoapps.com
4. **Host FQDN** = sharepoint1.contoso.local
5. **I can successfully ping** *anything*.contosoapps.com and it resolves to the IP for sharepoint1.contoso.local

***Via Powershell*:**

1. **$acct** = GetSPManagedAccount "contoso\spServices"
2. **$apppool** = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name SubscriptionAppPool - Account $acct
3. **$app** = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication - ApplicationPool $apppool -Name SubscriptionSettingSvcApp -DatabaseServer SP-SQL -DatabaseName SubscriptionSetting_Service_DB
4. **$proxy** = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $app

***Central Admin: Configure App URLs***

1. **App Domain** = contosoapps.com
2. **App Prefix** = app

***Central Admin: Manage App Catalog > Create New Catalog Site***

1. **Site URL** = http://sharepoint1/sites/AppCatalog
2. **Site Collection Admin** = contoso\spadmin
3. **Users/Groups** = NT Authority\Authenticated Users

***Central Admin: Configure Store Settings***

1. **App Purchases** = Yes
2. **Apps for Office from the Store** = No

---

When I go to "Add an App", then "SharePoint Store", I get this message:  **Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps.**

In Central Admin, when I go to **Manage Service Applications**,

1. **App Management Service Application**  is **STARTED**
2. **App Management Service Application Proxy**  is **STOPPED**
3. All other required services seem to be running, from what I can tell.

Could this have something to do with it?  If so, do I need to start this service from PowerShell?  I don't see a way to start it from within Central Admin.  As I stated earlier, I  am new to SP as well as PS!

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided!

Comment: Make sure your webapplication is connected to the App Management Service Application Proxy

Comment: Thanks for the response, Amal.  As I mentioned before, I am still very new to this.  How would one go about connecting the web application to the App Management Service Application Proxy?

Comment: Check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704550(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks again, Amal.  I just happened to find that same article prior to your response.  The web application was already connected to the App Management Service Application Proxy.  Any other ideas??

Answer (score 0):

As posted [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54279/start-application-proxy) and [here](https://tristanwatkins.com/fixing-the-usage-and-health-data-collection-sa/), you could try opening the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell and running these cmdlets:

```
$sap = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq “App Management Service Application Proxy”}
$sap.Provision()
```